# Регулярное выражение для описания повторяющихся кусков данных

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, python-3.x

Допустим есть такое регулярное выражение(шаблон):

`r'<[a-zA-Z-]+:[a-zA-Z-]+ [a-zA-Z]+="([a-zA-Z-]+:[a-zA-Z]+)"><([a-zA-Z-]+:[a-zA-Z_]+)>[a-zA-Z0-9]+</[a-zA-Z-]+:[a-zA-Z_]+>'`

Есть ли возможность описать, что определенная часть регулярного выражения должна повторяться некоторое количество раз(заранее неизвестно), например :`<([a-zA-Z-]+:[a-zA-Z_]+)>[a-zA-Z0-9]+</[a-zA-Z-]+:[a-zA-Z_]+>`?

Пробовал использовать {,}, но как я понял, данный оператор(?) подходит только к перечислению символов. прошу вашей помощи

Comment: Плохая идея регуляркой парсить xml/html :)

Comment: @gil9red а есть предложение, как быстрее выцепить необходимую строку?) если да, то можешь сказать( мне важна скорость)

Comment: Например, использовать парсер xml/html и через css-селектор или xpath-запрос вытащить. Вообще, если нацелились регуляркой вытащить, тогда лучше приложите к вопросу те данные и что из них нужно вытащить. Так шанс получить ответ будет выше. А разбираться в вашей регулярке мало кто будет -- проще свою написать :D

Comment: @gil9red , я только заметил ,xml парсится через lxml, регулярка нужна для того, чтобы из строки( которая поступает на вход , данные вытащить и их уже искать в xml(киплю уже)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

нашел ответ, достаточно использовать оператор | , который позволяет в поиске использовать 2 регулярных выражения , в моем случае, это выглядит так:`r'<[a-zA-Z-]+:[a-zA-Z-]+ [a-zA-Z]+="([a-zA-Z-]+:[a-zA-Z]+)">|<([a-zA-Z-]+:[a-zA-Z_]+)>[a-zA-Z0-9]+</[a-zA-Z-]+:[a-zA-Z_]+>'`
возвращать будет список  ,который состоит из список , в каждом из которых 2 элемента: первый - соответствует первому найденому выражению , второй ,соответственно,  второму. при чем записывается только первый найденный( т.е. один из элементов будет пустым)

Answer (score 0):

> что определенная часть регулярного выражения должна повторяться некоторое количество раз(заранее неизвестно)

По идее для этого предназначен `+` или `*`:

```
<[a-zA-Z-]+:[a-zA-Z-]+(\s+[a-zA-Z]+="([a-zA-Z-]+:[a-zA-Z]+)")*>
                      ^_____________________________________^^
```

и теперь у тега может быть люое количество атрибутов. Впрочем, с каким-то весьма ограниченным содержимым - по идее атрибуты надо не через `"([a-zA-Z-]+:[a-zA-Z]+)"` искать, а через `"[^"]*"`.

Comment: данный вариант не работает, так как `+` и `*` повторяют последовательность элементов, группы последовательностей не повторяются( узнад методом проб и ошибок)

Comment: @ddsds, в C# можно достать все совпадения группы: https://ideone.com/pcwUYk. Про питон не в курсе.